# tagging and graph "compression"

Tags: graph-theory, social-networking

I have a question on stack-overflow about "compressing" a graph. Suppose I have tags from a finite set T and objects from a finite set O. Moreover there are (uni-directional) links from elements of set of T to elements of set O. For example all the links are of the form

(a,b) where a belongs to T and b belongs to O. The set O can be huge compared to T and consequently the graph can be huge. But let me give you an example

Suppose O={o1,o2,o3}} and T={t1,t2,t3}

and I have the full set of allowed links

If I insert in the graph a hidden node h then I can create a graph with links

(o1,h), (o2,h), (o3,h) and (h,t1),(h,t2),(h,t3)

Then the tagging is preserved if we define that :

"object o has tag t if there is a path from o to t".

The definition as you see is invariant with the hidden node.

Moreover while previously I had 9 links, now I have 6 while the number of nodes is increased by 1.

For a fully linked case case with N objects and M tags the gain becomes

(NM)/(N+M) which as N increases the gain tends to M.

Do you know for such research? What category of problems this belongs? I am also very interested in the online case.

Comment: You might get more help with this at cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: For reference, [this question has been asked and answered on cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25785/tagging-and-graph-compression).